# Why am I getting an error (expected an order id to be passed) on production only?

Tags: php, paypal

I have implemented smart buttons on the site. There are no errors on the local machine (sandbox). But in production I get the error: Error: Expected an order id to be passed. The error appears when I click on the paypal button.

Paypal account is individual (not business).

Api keys checked - all ok.

I use PayPal SDK "paypal/paypal-checkout-sdk": "^1.0",

Below is the code. Tell me what could be the problem? Thanks.

VUE JS

```
<template>
  <div class="mt-3 text-center">
    <div v-show="!spinner" ref="paypal"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      spinner: false,
    };
  },
  props: {
    payment_info: Object,
  },

  mounted: function () {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    const ClientID = this.payment_info.agents.paypal.client_id;
    script.src = `https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=${ClientID}`;
    script.addEventListener("load", this.setLoaded);
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  },
  methods: {
    setLoaded() {
      var payment_id = this.payment_info.payment.id;
      var route_create_order = this.payment_info.routes.paypal.create_order;
      var route_capture_order = this.payment_info.routes.paypal.capture_order;

      window.paypal
        .Buttons({
          createOrder: () => {
            return axios
              .post(route_create_order, {
                paymentId: payment_id,
              })
              .then(function (res) {
                //   console.log(res.data);
                return res.data;
              })
              .then(function (data) {
                return data.id; // Use the same key name for order ID on the client and server
              });
          },

          onApprove: (data) => {

            this.spinner = true;

            return axios
              .post(route_capture_order, {
                orderID: data.orderID,
              })
              .then(function (res) {
                return res.data;
              })
              .then(function (details) {
                //  this.spinner = true;
                window.location.reload(false);
              });
          },

          onError: (err) => {
            this.spinner = false;
            alert(err);
            // console.log(err);
          },
        })
        .render(this.$refs.paypal);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

PHP Laravel

```
public function createOrder(Request $request, Payment $payment)
    {
        $order = new OrdersCreateRequest();
        $order->prefer('return=representation');
        $order->body = [
            "intent" => "CAPTURE",
            "purchase_units" => [[
                "amount" => [
                    "value" => $payment->sum,
                    "currency_code" => "USD",
                ],
                "payee" => [
                    "email_address" => config('money.paypal.email'),
                ],
 
            ]],
            "application_context" => [
                "cancel_url" => "https://example.com/cancel",
                "return_url" => "https://example.com/return",
            ],
        ];
 
        try {
            $response = self::client()->execute($order);
 
            $payment->agent_payment_id = $response->result->id;
            $payment->agent_name = Payment::AGENT_NAME__PAYPAL;
            $payment->save();
 
            return json_encode($response->result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
 
        } catch (HttpException $ex) {
            echo $ex->statusCode;
        }
 
    }

    public static function captureOrder(Request $request, Payment $payment)
    {
        $client = self::client();
 
        $orderId = $request->input('orderID');
        // Log::channel('debug')->info('captureOrder', ['data' => $request->all()]);
 
        $request = new OrdersCaptureRequest($orderId);
        $request->prefer('return=representation');
        try {
            // Call API with your client and get a response for your call
            $response = $client->execute($request);
 
            $agentPaymentId = $orderId;
            $agentName = Payment::AGENT_NAME__PAYPAL;
 
            return json_encode($response->result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        } catch (HttpException $ex) {
            return trans('app.error');
        }
 
    }
 
    public static function client()
    {
        return new PayPalHttpClient(self::environment());
    }
 
    public static function environment()
    {
        $clientId = config('app.paypal_client_id');
        $clientSecret = config('app.paypal_client_secret');
        return new SandboxEnvironment($clientId, $clientSecret);
    }
```

This error appears not only in production. And in the local environment. It is only associated with credentials.

There is no error with these credentials:

```
PAYPAL_EMAIL = sandbox@email
PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID=sandbox_client_id
PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET=sandbox_client_secret
```

When I change the data to this, I get an error: Expected an order id to be passed

```
PAYPAL_EMAIL = production@email
PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID=production_client_id
PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET=production_client_secret
```

This error (Expected an order id to be passed) is sent by the paypal in response to our request.

Comment: Look at the call to route_create_order in your browser. What is happening? Probably a credential or TLS connectivity problem causing your server to not be able to create the order and return an order id, but you need to debug this within your PHP if the error doesn't show.

Comment: @PrestonPHX route_create_order works correctly.
it runs the method createOrder (see above example)
where the paypal exception is triggered
`catch (HttpException $ex) {
            echo $ex->statusCode;
}`
Message: Error: Expected an order id to be passed.
This exception is returned by the paypal server. No php.
This error is not present on the local machine (sandbox account). Only in production.
I have a suspicion that the paypal smart buttons do not work with physical accounts.

Comment: That is not at all what I meant. You are doing an axios post to route_create_order, and you need to debug the response message in production, as well as what is happening on the server if the response message does not illuminate the problem.

Comment: @PrestonPHX

This error appears not only in production. And in the local environment. It is only associated with credentials.

There is no error with these credentials:

PAYPAL_EMAIL = sandbox@email
PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID=sandbox_client_id
PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET=sandbox_client_secret


When I change the data to this, I get an error: Expected an order id to be passed

PAYPAL_EMAIL = production@email
PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID=production_client_id
PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET=production_client_secret

What could be the problem?

ps For ease of reading, I brought the code into question.

Comment: `return new SandboxEnvironment($clientId, $clientSecret);` , if you are calling this with production credentials, that is precisely the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue appears to be using production credentials in the sandbox environment

```
return new SandboxEnvironment($clientId, $clientSecret);
```

If production credentials are passed to this code path, this will fail to obtain an access token (HTTP 4xx error) , and hence the API requests that depend on an access token will fail and not be able to obtain an order ID, and hence the client-side code calling `route_create_order` and expecting to receive an order ID back from the server will fail.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wrote this and everything works: 
return new ProductionEnvironment($clientId, $clientSecret);
I couldn't solve this error for a week. I asked many places and did not help anywhere. Only your answer. Thank you!