# paypal with react js thrown an error "Expected an order id to be passed" even tho i pass the order id

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, paypal

this is my react js code

```
<PayPalScriptProvider options={{ "client-id": "sssss" }}>
  <PayPalButtons
    createOrder={(data, actions) => {
      return actions.order
        .create({
          purchase_units: [
            {
              amount: {
                value: totalPrice,
              },
            },
          ],
        })
        .then((order) => {
          const orderId = order.id;
          this.setState({ orderId: orderId });
          return orderId;
        });
    }}
    onApprove={(data, actions) => {
      const orderId = data.orderID; // Use data.orderID to retrieve the order ID
      return actions.order
        .capture(orderId)
        .then((details) => {
          const transactionId = details.id;
          this.setState({ payment_id: transactionId }, () => {
            this.confirmorder();
          });
          return details;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }}
  />
</PayPalScriptProvider>
```

but in the console this error is disply

```
{err: 'Error: Expected an order id to be passed\n    at ht…UDdqShnjXZQ7gz8qq7i5Dc4RQ8teV7-4GmR_vwL5:3:15672)', timestamp: '1688213679563', referer: 'www.sandbox.paypal.com', sdkCorrelationID: 'f203730b70585', sessionID: 'uid_bfe95a339e_mte6nta6mzk', …}
```

get rid of this?

simple question was ask here

[Paypal Expected an order id to be passed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57197907/paypal-expected-an-order-id-to-be-passed)

[Why am I getting an error (expected an order id to be passed) on production only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64864786/why-am-i-getting-an-error-expected-an-order-id-to-be-passed-on-production-only)

i try this and no hope at all

```
const onApprove = (data, actions) => {
  const orderId = this.state.orderId;
  return actions.order
    .capture(orderId)
    .then((details) => {
      const transactionId = details.id;
      this.setState({ payment_id: transactionId }, () => {
        this.confirmorder();
      });
      return details;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

Comment: `console.log(orderId)` before returning it, and backtrack from there. Use the Network tab -> Response subtab as well. seems basic debugging is in order